# After last comma remaining characters has to merge with next line using regex(notepad++)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to merge all characters with next line after the last comma of that line using Regex in Notepad++.

## Example:

```
String class also, supports regular, expressions, which makes it more powerful
Its true.
```

## OUTPUT:

```
String class also, supports regular, expressions,
which makes it more powerful Its true.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: expected results?

Answer (score 2):

Use regex pattern `([\w ,]+, )([\w ]+)\n([\w ]+\.)`

Then for replacement use `$1\n$2 $3`

See for example : [regexr.com/45bhd](https://regexr.com/45bhd)

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex:

```
 , ([^,]+?$)\n(.+)
```

`, ([^,]+?$)` matches the last comma on a line, and all the characters after it. This also captures the part after the comma into group 1.

Then a new line is matched `\n`.

Then we match everything on that line and capture it into group 2 `(.+)`. You could also use `*` instead of `+` if you want to match empty lines as well.

The match looks like this:

[image]

Now we just need to replace the match with this replacement:

```
,\n$1 $2
```

Answer (score 0):

Find expression: `(.+),(.+)\n`

Replace expression: `$1\n$2`

---

**EDIT 1**

To also consume space characters after the comma, use find expression `(.+),\s+(.+)\`

Answer (score 0):

Capture the end of the line starting from last comma: `,\s*([^,]+?)\s*[\r\n]+`.
Depending on the EOL convention, you can adjust the last part as `\r`, `\n` or `\n\r`.

Then replace it with: `\n\1` (with a space at the end).